# Giving classes to elements to style them in foundation 5

Tags: class, css, zurb-foundation

I give classes to elements to style them and all is good but one thing is not. The .active doesn't do the thing. It's supposed to change the color. What's wrong with my code ?

```
   <nav class="top-bar">
     <ul class="title-area">
       <li class="name"><h1><a href="#">Queen</a></h1></li>  
     </ul>
   <section class="top-bar-section">                
    <ul class="left">           
     <li class="divider"> </li>   
     <li class="active"> <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
     <li class="divider"> </li> 
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </section>
   </nav>

.top-bar-section ul li:hover > a {
    background: #272727;
    color: white; }
.top-bar-section ul li.active > a {
    background: yellow;
    color: white; }
.top-bar-section ul li.active > a:hover {
      background: #0078a0; }
```

It works when I write this thing : .top-bar-section ul.left li.active {}  but hey it should work without putting .left here too right ? well it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know exactly what your going through [Tomas.R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225109/tomas-r), and what it boils down to is **CSS Specificity**. Which is the fancy way of saying that the more specific a CSS selector/rule is the greater it's influence. Since `.top-bar-section ul.left li.active` works, but `.top-bar-section ul li.active` doesn't my guess is that somewhere in Foundation's CSS there is a selector/rule that is more specific than `.top-bar-section ul li.active`.

A great way to determine how specific Foundation's selectors/rules are is to use your browser's development tools, usually F12, and look at the element/tag you want to change. If you see that Foundation was very granular in specifying the CSS selector/rule then you will need to do the same.

Remember that you don't have to be more specific, just as specific, as Foundation's selectors/rules, as long as you are "closer" to the element/tag as in:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />`
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" />
```

This way your `site.css` will be closer to your HTML then Foundation's CSS.

To get a better understanding about **CSS Specificity** check out these links:

- [Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)
- [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
- [Specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/)

Lastly, depending on how much you are planning on customizing it might be a better strategy to look into [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Zurb gets you going with [Getting Started With Sass](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) and there are a lot of great tutorials online to pick up where it leaves off.

I hope that helps.

Comment: THAT Ladies and Gentlemen is how the answer should be replied. Thanks, Adam.